# Why is $\sqrt{|x-2|}$ continuous but not differentiable at x=2?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Why is $\sqrt{|x-2|}$ continuous but not differentiable at x=2?

I thought that if there exists a limit on both sides then it would be differentiable?

Comment: "I thought that if there exists a limit on both sides then it would be differentiable?" A limit of *what*? Don't use pronouns here - be *specific*.

Comment: No, for it to be differentiable it also must not be a cusp, corner, nor vertical tangent. In this case, there is a cusp thus not differentiable. Differentiability implies continuity but *not* vise-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the graph of $f:=\sqrt{\vert x-2 \vert}$ where $-5 \leq x \leq 5$:

[image]

Here $f$ is a continuous curve but there is a "corner" at $x=2$, so $f$ is not differentiable there.

For the formal argument, the limit 
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{\vert 2+h-2 \vert} \;-\sqrt{\vert 2-2 \vert} }{h}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{\vert h \vert}}{h} $$ does't exist!

Answer (score 2):

Since

$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{|2+h-2|}-\sqrt{|2-2|}}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|h|}}$$

does not exist, $\sqrt{|x-2|}$ is not differentiable at $x=2$. (Althogh both $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+}\sqrt{|x-2|}$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^-}\sqrt{|x-2|}$ exist.)

Answer (score 2):

Functions can be continuous without being differentiable.  This is an example.  If the function has a corner it isn't differentiable at that point.  A simpler example is $f(x)=|x|$ around $x=0$.  At any point less than $0$ the derivative is $-1$.  At any point greater than $0$ the derivative is $1$.  If you try to apply the definition of the derivative at $0$ you will fail.  We have $$f'(0)=\left.\frac {df(x)}{dx}\right|_{x=0}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac {f(h)-f(0)}h=\begin {cases}-1&x \lt 0\\1 & x \gt 0 \end {cases}$$ and there is no limit at $0$ so $f$ is not differentiable there.

Answer (score 1):

If a function is differentiable, then it implies that it is continuous. However, the opposite is not true.

For example:  |x| is not differentiable at x=0, although it's continuous.
Also for this function $\sqrt|x-2|$, the right hand limit at x=2 and left hand limit at x=2 does not match, so limit doesn't exist at x=2, hence not differentiable.

$$\\
\textbf{LHL: } \lim_{h\rightarrow 2^{-}} \frac{ f(2+h)-f(2)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 2^{-}} \frac{ \sqrt (2+h-2)-\sqrt(2-2)}{h}\\ =\lim_{h\rightarrow 2^{-}} \frac{ \sqrt (h)-\sqrt(0)}{h}\\ =\lim_{h\rightarrow 2^{-}} \frac{ \sqrt (h)}{h} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}
\\
 \textbf{RHL: } \lim_{h\rightarrow 2^{+}} \frac{ f(2+h)-f(2)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 2^{+}} \frac{ \sqrt (2-h-2)-\sqrt(2-2)}{h}\\ =\lim_{h\rightarrow 2^{+}} \frac{ \sqrt (-h)-\sqrt(0)}{h}\\ =\lim_{h\rightarrow 2^{+}} \frac{ \sqrt (-h)}{h} = \text{not defined}\\ \\\\ \because \textbf{RHL} \neq \textbf{LHL}
$$
This is not a differentiable at x=2

Another simple way to check for differentiability is that there should not be a sharp corner in the curve.

In the plot of the $\sqrt|x-2|$, this corner occurs at $ x=2 $ (as shown in the figure)
[plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAhc8.png)